# strconv.ParseInt gives 0

Tags: string, parsing, go, strconv

I'm trying to parse a file of this forme:

```
12
0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5
1,0,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,2,3,4
2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,4,3,2,3
3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2
1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4
2,1,2,3,1,0,1,2,2,1,2,3
3,2,1,2,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2
4,3,2,1,3,2,1,0,4,3,2,1
2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3
3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,1,0,1,2
4,3,2,3,3,2,1,2,2,1,0,1
5,4,3,2,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,0
0,5,2,4,1,0,0,6,2,1,1,1
5,0,3,0,2,2,2,0,4,5,0,0
2,3,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,2,2,2
4,0,0,0,5,2,2,10,0,0,5,5
1,2,0,5,0,10,0,0,0,5,1,1
0,2,0,2,10,0,5,1,1,5,4,0
0,2,0,2,0,5,0,10,5,2,3,3
6,0,5,10,0,1,10,0,0,0,5,0
2,4,5,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,10,10
1,5,2,0,5,5,2,0,0,0,5,0
1,0,2,5,1,4,3,5,10,5,0,2
1,0,2,5,1,0,3,0,10,0,2,0
```

Where the first line give us the size of the matrix: `n x n`
The n-following lines are the matrix D. Then the n-following lines are the matrix W. So there is `2n + 1` lines.

Here is the code to parse it and put it in variables.

```
func readFile(path string) (int64, Matrix, Matrix) {
    // open the file
    f, _ := os.Open(path)
    defer f.Close()

    // init the new reader on the opened file
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)

    // we get the n value
    line, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    splitedLine := strings.Fields(line)
    tmp, _ := strconv.ParseInt(splitedLine[0], 10, 64)
    n := int64(tmp)

    // we init the matrix W and D
    D := Matrix{}
    D.matrix = make([][]int64, n)
    for i, _ := range D.matrix {
        D.matrix[i] = make([]int64, n)
    }

    W := Matrix{}
    W.matrix = make([][]int64, n)
    for i, _ := range W.matrix {
        W.matrix[i] = make([]int64, n)
    }

    // loop on the n first element
    iter := int64(0)
    for iter < n {
        // we get the n following elements
        line, _ = r.ReadString('\n')
        for index, ele := range strings.Split(line, ",") {
            D.matrix[iter][index], _ = strconv.ParseInt(ele, 10, 64)
        }
        iter++
    }

    iter = 0
    for iter < n {
        // we get the n following elements
        line, _ = r.ReadString('\n')
        for index, ele := range strings.Split(line, ",") {
            W.matrix[iter][index], _ = strconv.ParseInt(ele, 10, 64)
        }
        iter++
    }

    return n, W, D

}
```

The resultat for W should be like:

```
[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
[ 2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  3.],
[ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  5.,  4.,  3.,  2.],
[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
[ 2.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
[ 3.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
[ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.],
[ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
[ 3.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
[ 4.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
[ 5.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]
```

But when I print it; it gives me :

```
[0 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 0]
[1 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 0]
[2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 4 3 2 0]
[3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 0]
[1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 1 2 3 0]
[2 1 2 3 1 0 1 2 2 1 2 0]
[3 2 1 2 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 0]
[4 3 2 1 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 0]
[2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 0]
[3 2 3 4 2 1 2 3 1 0 1 0]
[4 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 0 0]
[5 4 3 2 4 3 2 1 3 2 1 0]
```

I don't know why.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: could you please paste the defination of `Matrix`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Know that [`Reader.ReadString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) returns you a `string` value with the delimieter. So `r.ReadString('\n')` will return you a string with the trailing newline character.

And when you split the string at the commas, the last part will contain the newline character, and attempting to parse the number from it will fail, as shown in this example:

```
line := "0,1,2\n"
for _, ele := range strings.Split(line, ",") {
    fmt.Println(strconv.ParseInt(ele, 10, 64))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tR_Ef0c2qo)):

```
0 <nil>
1 <nil>
0 strconv.ParseInt: parsing "2\n": invalid syntax
```

You religiously omit error checks, don't do that! As you can see in the above example, checking and printing the error returned by `strconv.ParseInt()` immediately revealed the error and what's going wrong.

What you may do is cut the trailing newline character before attempting to parse any number from it, e.g.:

```
strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(ele), 10, 64)
```

Or use the [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) which can scan lines and it cuts trailing newlines automatically.